# Understanding variable in cmd shell

Tags: windows, shell, variables, cmd

In some shell script for windows I cam across some syntax that I could not understand.
If someone have the patient to explain me what it does and why it is like that would be great.

The first things is what the !! is about. Some variable are surrounded by ! and I don't understand the reason for it Ex:

```
!DATE!
!timeMM:~0,1!
...
```

Second is (what I guess is) a kind of variable substitution. 
Some variable end with `:"=` but I have no clue what it does. Ex:

```
set cmdlin=%cmdlin:"=%
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Exclamation marks are used for delayed variables expansion. You can read more about it in `cmd /?`.
2. Yes, it is substitution. In this case double quotation mark is substituted with an empty string. You can read more about it in `set /?`.